# Randrange dependent on variable - Python

Tags: python, random, floating-point

Im trying to make random co-ords for a object spawning onto a canvas(The canvas is the size of the users screen so the range is ever changing.)

```
random.randrange(12.5, int(resX-12.5))
```

This is the line of code resX being the variable that stores the size of the users screen resolution, 12.5 being the radius of the shape being spawned.

The error i'm getting is that the resX part isn't an integer
`ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()`

Im not sure if theres a way to use a variable within the random line?

Comment: Do you want a random float or random int?

Comment: random int cause its for co-ords, cant use float for that

Comment: _"cause its for co-ords, cant use float for that"_ - that argument doesn't hold. Lat/lon are coords, and we use floats for that. GPU buffers contain coords, and we use floats for that. Are you sure you don't want floats? Note that the accepted answer gives you floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `random.uniform` for getting a random float number between a specific range:

```
>>> resX = 100
>>> random.uniform(12.5, int(resX-12.5))
55.797969682558296
```

Note that since you can pass a float number as the range into `uniform()` you might don't need to call the `int` function on `resX-12.5` but since this change may affect the result, it depends on what you want.Otherwise you can do it like following:

```
>>> random.uniform(12.5, resX-12.5)
66.1303523838728
```

Comment: The `int` is probably now unnecessary

Comment: @Eric Indeed, but since it may affect the result I'll mention that too.

Comment: okay so range isnt the right one when using variables?
thanks

Comment: @StanleyRoyChilton No it's exactly what you've passed to `randint()` function.

Comment: sorry yeah i meant randint

Comment: @StanleyRoyChilton: You seem to think that "integers" and "variables" are disjoint sets, based on your interpretation of the original error. This is false. `uniform` works for `float`s, `randrange` works for `int`s.

Comment: yeah i worked that out after reading this answer i was just confirming what i was thinking